# Scale Raphael paper

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

What is the most correct way to scale Raphael.js paper element?
I have found one way:

```
var paper = Raphael('container', 300, 300);
var circle = paper.circle(40, 40, 25).attr({fill: 'red', stroke: 'gray', 'stroke-width': '4px'});
paper.setViewBox(0, 0, 300, 300);
paper.canvas.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');
paper.setSize(1200, 1200);
// Now circle is resized
```

But it seems that it's not relevant to my problem.

Comment: seems perfectly valid. what is the exact problem?

Comment: @EliranMalka this method changes the grid of canvas. I though it would be another way. But, finally I have done it in my own way.

Comment: if by "changes the grid" you mean the proportions are warped, just adjust the `preserveAspectRatio`.